# Javascript open new tab in iOS Chrome with name

Tags: javascript

I have seen a lot of posts about this problem. I've tried many of them but none worked for me.

**Approach 1.**

```
if (window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('crios') > -1) {//iOS Chrome
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var myFileName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
    reader.fileName = myFileName;
    reader.onload = function () {
        window.open(reader.result, "_blank");
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(iosBlob);
    return;
}
```

**Approach 2.**

```
if (window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('crios') > -1) {//iOS Chrome
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var myFileName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
    reader.onload = function () {
        window.open(reader.result, "_blank");
        window.document.title = myFileName;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(iosBlob);
    return;
}
```

Both still shows the "iosBlob" variable content in title.

Comment: For security reasons, you probably can't avoid that.

Comment: Have you considered dynamically generating a page and passing a custom HTML title tag?

Comment: @IlanP my new tab is actually a PDF file. The piece of code in my post is part of onClick function on a file link, upon clicking, PDF file will be downloaded and displayed in new tab. How do I dynamically generate a page with PDF inside?